# Error 2349 when dealing with union type of generic T and function

Tags: typescript

How do I fix below code to solve 2349?

```js
function fillArray<T>(arr: T[], value: T | ((index: number) => T)): void {
    if (typeof value === 'function') {
        for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            arr[i] = value(i)
        }
    } else {
        arr.fill(value)
    }
}
```

TypeScript report error for `value(i)` as:

> This expression is not callable.
> Not all constituents of type '((index: number) => T) | (T & Function)' are callable.

See: [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=10&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMGAbVBBATlghgTwB4AVAPgApccAuRYgbQF0AaRAN11RAFNbjEAPonLkYYACbcAHrTAgAtgCNuWAJSIAvKTqrVtNnBjjEAbwCwAKETXEMYMKj4ADtzj2OXbpo0bEAclBIWAQ-dXMrG0jgOCxhVG4oW01EAAYAbiTCRCosADp4sABzKAALDJgAagqwy0i6mxz6GEZkjx5RVVr6xABfLusexG5UAGcvcO7snFyUdHI27k6Igcs+iyA)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what exactly causes the error (might be related to this [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13995) with narrowing generic type parameters).

As a workaround, you can define and use [custom type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards):

```
function isFunction<T>(value: T | ((index: number) => T)): value is (index: number) => T {
    return typeof value === 'function';
}
    
function fillArray<T>(arr: T[], value: T | ((index: number) => T)): void {
    if (isFunction(value)) {
        for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            arr[i] = value(i)
        }
    } else {
        arr.fill(value)
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABDAzgMXNeYA8AVAPgAoA3AQwBsQBTALkT0QB9EiiYwATagD3rBABbAEbUATgEpEAXgIMJE+uSrVkKVh259EAkeKmyGiAN4BYAFCIriMdSggxSKAE8ADtTjBEymjOnTEAHJQSFgEQIBuCwBfCwsQrAREYBgKCgBBMTEyZ3xiMiz6PABtAF0AGm9KGiLmVnYuXn4hUUkZOTwFJTgYThMLa2QvdnRMMLBSauoFfstB62A4MVYKO2QZRAAGCPWcRAKxADpVsABzKAALHZgAahupMzn5+YPimFKNn2p2CQHnxFiTwBiGoFBQqke-32WUOKTSkxUvyBgMBQA)

---

Other working option discovered by @VLAZ is using `instanceof` guard instead of `typeof`:

```
function fillArray<T>(arr: T[], value: T | ((index: number) => T)): void {
    if (value instanceof Function) {
        for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            arr[i] = value(i)
        }
    } else {
        arr.fill(value)
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMGAbVBBATlghgTwB4AVAPgApccAuRYgbQF0AaRAN11RAFNbjEAPonLkYYACbcAHrTAgAtgCNuWAJSIAvKTqrVtNnBjjEAbwCwAKETXEMYMI5dutsAGcouSNzj2AYuGh4MHVzKxtw4DgsYVRuKFtNRAAGAG4EwkQqLAA6WLAAcygACzSYAGoykMtwmpss+hhGRMceUVVq2sQAXw7rLsRuVFdnUM7MnGyUdHIW7nawvsseiyA)

---

One more working option - make the array type a generic parameter:

```
function fillArray<A extends Array<unknown>>(
    arr: A,
    value: A[number] | ((index: number) => A[number])
): void {
    if (typeof value === 'function') {
        for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            arr[i] = value(i)
        }
    } else {
        arr.fill(value)
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMGAbVBBATlghgTwB4NEBTADylLABMBnRbPI8AazDgHcwA+HgCgCwAKERjEuHAC5GAGhHjEAN1yoQpGRgDaYEAFsARqSwBdRAB9E-fjFoUZuw8YCUiALw9GO-UdPORzjJKcDA0iADeCuIwwFZQ+AAOpHCxKmqk7m5uiADkoJCwCDmukaKK4sBwWFaopFCIMO6IAAwA3A2IhBI4AHS1YADmUAAW7TAA1OMlUeXlklhaMGbZaeo2-mWzAL4ziFtkqHQZpbNi8z0o6PyrpBuKO8IPIjSkEKiSGRAIdPXzDj7GLQmdoiESXTA4Aj8eayRAARgATABmZytMFoCHMaE4WH8VweeHI1Gg4To9BMKEwqz4zw5RFI4po4Tgin4bFYWFQLDqVFAA)

Comment: I think `value instanceof Function` also works in correctly narrowing the type.

Comment: [Forgot the link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMGAbVBBATlghgTwB4AVAPgApccAuRYgbQF0AaRAN11RAFNbjEAPonLkYYACbcAHrTAgAtgCNuWAJSIAvKTqrVtNnBjjEAbwCwAKETXEMYMI5dutsAGcouSNzj2AYuGh4MHVzKxtw4DgsYVRuKFtNRAAGAG4EwkQqLAA6WLAAcygACzSYAGoykMtwmpss+hhGRMceUVVq2sQAXw7rLsRuVFdnUM7MnGyUdHIW7nawvssei0tQSFgEW1dgchlMsHw9RCktxH91oNNexCw4kCwkKHwAB297E41PxAAiNcCEb4pJZAA)

Comment: Yes, you're right. Interesting why, can't find anything related to this

Comment: Me neither. I can neither explain it, neither can I find a reason. I was going to post it as an answer but since I cannot justify it, I'll leave it as a comment. It might very well be a bug *in* the known issue, which makes it correct? Not sure. Or might be some fix that went in and halfway fixed it. It's interesting that `typeof value === "function"` also partially works. In the `else` `value` is treated as `T` only.

Comment: @VLAZ making the array type as a generic parameter also works.. Probably this is not exactly related to linked issue
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMGAbVBBATlghgTwB4NEBTADylLABMBnRbPI8AazDgHcwA+HgCgCwAKERjEuHAC5GAGhHjEAN1yoQpGRgDaYEAFsARqSwBdRAB9E-fjFoUZuw8YCUiALw9GO-UdPORzjJKcDA0iADeCuIwwFZQ+AAOpHCxKmqk7m5uiADkoJCwCDmukaKK4sBwWFaopFCIMO6IAAwA3A2IhBI4AHS1YADmUAAW7TAA1OMlUeXlklhaMGbZaeo2-mWzAL4ziFtkqHQZpbNi8z0o6PyrpBuKO8JbQANQfH5w1dQAL6XH3jaZNBDd4bOCbLS6OxPCCvEZfaQfIA

Comment: That one I can understand. Because there shouldn't be an overlap between `A` and a function. I suspect `T` doesn't work because it *might* overlap. Then again `typeof` doesn't filter it out but `instanceof` does, so I really don't understand what's happening. I thought the two should do the same thing butt hey don't. To me, a user defined type guard does seem like the surest way to implement this. At least then I would expect that a future version wouldn't break it. I suspect an `instanceof` might regress. And I find it easier to read than constraining the generic parameter.